# c compiler on own website to test users input

Tags: c, browser, compiler-construction

i know my question sounds maybe a little bit stupid or unreachable but i will try:

Is there any existing tool in the WWW that i can use **on my own website** to test users c language input and display the output of it when existing?

I know there are sites like: http://ideone.com/ who does this and so it should be possible but how is it possible for a normal user to put something like this on his own website?

I already found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443669/running-c-code-directly-in-the-browser) on stackoverflow but idk if that is what i'm looking for.

Thanks

**Edit1: I tried some hard coded html just for test this plugin without wp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>Test run-this Plugin</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="Kurzbeschreibung" />
    <link href="run_this.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="run_this.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <h2> C example</h2>
    <pre lang="c" line="1" class="run-this">
        #include &lt;stdio.h&gt;

        int main (int argc, char** argv) {
           printf("Hello, World!");
           return 0;
        }
    </pre>

    <div class="run-this-button">
        <input type="button" value="Run" onclick='run_this(this, "c", "CSNpbmNsdWRlICZsdDtzdGRpby5oJmd0Ow0KDQoJaW50IG1haW4gKGludCBhcmdjLCBjaGFyKiogYXJndikgew0KCSAgcHJpbnRmKCJIZWxsbywgV29ybGQhIik7DQoJICByZXR1cm4gMDsNCgl9");'/>
         <img class="run-this-spinner" src="spinner.gif"/>
    </div>
    <div class="run-this-details"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

but i get the error: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://run-this.appspot.com/runthis. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

**Edit2:**
Now it runs :) i just had to move the folder to a server and it works.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/run-this/

Comment: Can i use wordpress plugins without using wordpress?

Comment: Finally solved it. Thanks for the plugin! I only have to add some textfield_input_send_to_javascript_stuff and it's solved. But with the hard coded html it already works.

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this -

1. Have a python or any other way to run shell commands on your server
2. When the user want to run his page simply save it and run a shell command to the c compiler you have while having the output saved into another file
3. Read the output file and show it online.

This can be done, though i mind you that there are MANY MANY security holes that you must check before letting any code run on your server!  Many people can use it to hack your server or even make it a part of a botnet.

Comment: It's just for a selected part of people. So the security holes are not the problem.
But isn't their any plugin like the "run-this" for wordpress just without wordpress requirements that does the same? Something js/jQuery only. Where the code is sent to ideone or something and the request shown as result?